# How to cmap a local function?

Tags: key-bindings, expression-register

I'd like to reproduce this zsh mapping:

```sh
smart_dot() {
  if [[ $LBUFFER = *.. ]]; then
    LBUFFER+=/..
  else
    LBUFFER+=.
  fi
}
zle -N smart_dot
bindkey -M viins -- . smart_dot
```

At first I used this:

```js
function! Smart_dot() abort
  if getcmdtype() =~# '[:]'
    let l:cmd=getcmdline()
    if match(l:cmd, '\.\.$') !=-1
      return '/..'
    else
      return "."
    endif
  else
    return getcmdline()
  endif
endfunction
cnoremap . <c-r>=Smart_dot()<CR>
```

but how do turn this into local function? I've tried many variants on this that wouldn't work because it complained `<SID>` was not used in a script context. Do I need to use `<c-r>=` or `<c-\>e`? Do I need to use the `expand(<sfile>)` trick to get the script number, described near the end of section `:h script-local`? Or do I need to `<Plug>` this? I'm confused.

```
" function! s:smart_dot() ...
cnoremap . <C-\>ecall(function('<SID>smart_dot()'), [])<CR>
```

Comment: You should check `:h :map-<expr>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `<sid>` directly in this context like any other key code:

```
cnoremap . <c-r>=<sid>Smart_dot()<cr>
```

The reason is the `*map` family of commands are special in that they convert key codes to actual real characters.  For example, `<cr>` is converted to a carriage return, code 13, and `<c-r>` is converted to code 18.

Comment: thanks. When I tried this before, neovim segfaulted, but the function was a little different, so that must have been another issue.